# Azure Sql Database stuck "Restoring"

Tags: sql-server, azure, database

I aborted the restore of an Azure Sql database over 2 weeks ago. While no longer visible in the Azure Portal it continues to appear in the list of database In Sql Server Management Studio. "(Restoring...)" appears after the database name. Similarly it appears in the list returned buy *Select * from sys.databases*. However *Drop Database* returns

```
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 8<br/>
Database '<db name>' does not exist.
```

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try if `USE [master]; ALTER DATABASE [<db name>] SET ONLINE` brings the database out of restoring state but that might not work in yout case.

You may need to bring the database to a working state at first and therefor restore it by using the `WITH RECOVERY` option, with your database `RESTORE` command, to bring your database online as part of the restore process.

That can be done using the restore database wizard in SQL Server Management Studio. This way you can select the overwrite option, and the WITH Recovery option.

If neither of those work [Azure PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqlinstancedatabase) will be your last chance:

```
Remove-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -Name "Database01" -InstanceName "managedInstance1" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -Force
```

In an on premise environment you could stop the SQL Server Service, rename or delete the DB and Log files, start the SQL Service to being able to delete the (then failed) database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have however tried these. Alter Database gives 
Msg 42008, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
ODBC error: State: 28000: Error: 18456 Message:'[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '##MS_InstanceCertificate##'.'.

RESTORE gives
Msg 40510, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Statement 'RESTORE DATABASE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Improved the answer with Azure PowerShell command. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, just create a new database of the same name. And the restoring one will be replaced with the one created, then you can delete it.